# Passing dynamic query params to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have following code

```
<ng-template #listItem let-itemData="data">
<div class="overlay-card">
<div class="card-header">
  <span class="card-header-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
  <h3>{{ itemData.name }}</h3>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="card-body-text" *ngFor="let item of itemData.dataList">
    <a [routerLink]="['/users']"
      [queryParams]="{organizationId: item.organizationId, organizationName: item.organizationName, userId: item.id}"
      [innerHTML]="item.name | highlight: searchText">{{ item.name }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer">
  <div class="button-container" *ngIf="formattedSearchData.users.length !== searchData?.users.length && formattedSearchData.users.length > 0"
    (click)="loadMoreSearchData('users')">
    <span class="load-button-text">Load</span> <span class="footer-number">({{ searchData?.users.length -
      formattedSearchData.users.length }})</span>
  </div>
</div>
</ng-template>
```

My question is in the part

```
<a [routerLink]="['/users']"
  [queryParams]="{organizationId: item.organizationId, organizationName: item.organizationName, userId: item.id}"
  [innerHTML]="item.name | highlight: searchText">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

can I pass dynamic [queryParams] something like

```
<a [routerLink]="{someDynamicValue}"
  [queryParams]="{organizationId: item.organizationId, organizationName: item.organizationName, {someDynamicValue}: item.id}"
  [innerHTML]="item.name | highlight: searchText">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

Note the places where I need Dynamic Values and if possible how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the generating of queryParams out of your template like so:

```
this.someDynamicValue = 'user';
this.queryParamString = {
  organizationId: 'organization.id',
  organizationName: 'your own org name',
  [this.someDynamicValue]: 1,
};
```

and then in your template:

```
<a [routerLink]="someDynamicValue"
  [queryParams]="queryParamString"
  [innerHTML]="item.name | highlight: searchText">{{ item.name }}</a>
```